# Mac OS Sandbox: Launching main application from helper

Tags: macos, appstore-sandbox

I have create in sandbox, an app which use a helper to start at login, as presented [here](http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/).

It works ok, but the next messages are logged in the console:

`lsboxd[1560]: Not allowing process 15208 to launch "/Applications/SandboxApp.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/SandboxHelper.app" because it has not been launched previously by the user`

`lsboxd[1560]: Not allowing process 15208 to register app "/Applications/SandboxApp.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/SandboxHelper.app" for launch.`

I see that this messages are about the helper, but I don't know what to do, to prevent them.

My only concern is that Apple may reject the app because of this messages.

Is someone who prevent the raise of those sandbox messages, or is someone who sent an app, which raise sandbox messages, to Apple and was accepted on Appstore?

Answer (score 3):

See http://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/ - according to this it is a code-signing issue that probably won't be an issue with the AppStore build as the AppStore build gets resigned.

Answer (score 2):

This should work in the final build. According to [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/security/conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW29) (Section “Launching Helpers with Launch Services”):

> ### Launching Helpers with Launch Services
>
> A sandboxed app is allowed to
>   launch a helper using Launch Services if at least one of these
>   conditions has been met:
>
> - Both the app and helper pass the Gatekeeper assessment. By default
>     that means both are signed by the Mac App Store or with a Developer
>     ID. Note: This does not include your development ("Mac Developer") or
>     distribution ("3rd Party Mac Developer Application") signing
>     identities.
> - The app is installed in /Applications and the app bundle
>     and all contents are owned by root.
> - The helper has been (manually) run
>     at least once by the user.

The first and/or second one should cover your case when your app was installed through the Mac App Store.